# Paypal "PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED" Only for REST API?

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to integrating Paypal on my application. This application will allow people to sell tokens between them. So the money doesn't go to me, but to the payees.

I first used smart button directly on my front-end (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/). I just had to add a payee field and it worked perfectly fine. 0 bug, no issue.

But now, I want to make the integration on a NodejS back-end, because it is more secure for me.

And despite I am doing exactly the same thing (create order -> capturing order), I am getting this error :

```json
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","details": [{
    "issue":"PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED","description":"Payee does not have appropriate consent to 
    allow the API caller to process this type of transaction on their behalf. Your current 
    setup requires the 'payee' to provide a consent before this transaction can be 
    processed successfully."
  }],
 "message": "Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.",
 "debug_id":"300756d694c77","links": [{
   "href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-PAYEE_NOT_CONSENTED",
   "rel":"information_link","method":"GET"
  }]
}
```

Why ? Why it has no issue doing this kind of operation with smart button, but I can't do it with the checkout sdk on nodejs and need the payee consent ?

Whats the difference ?

Needing the consent or any kind of operation from the payee is really annoying for me, because I need payee to sell their tokens with the minimal of action to do it.

And I don't see whats the difference between doing it with smart button, or with a back-end.

Btw here is my code :

```js
const paypal = require('@paypal/checkout-server-sdk')

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod") {
    APP_SETTINGS = require('src/PRIVATE_APP_SETTINGS.json').prod;
    var environment = new paypal.core.LiveEnvironment(APP_SETTINGS.paypal.paypal_client_id, APP_SETTINGS.paypal.paypal_secret);
} else {
    APP_SETTINGS = require('src/PRIVATE_APP_SETTINGS.json').dev;
    var environment = new paypal.core.SandboxEnvironment(APP_SETTINGS.paypal.paypal_client_id, APP_SETTINGS.paypal.paypal_secret);
}

var client = new paypal.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);


function createPayment(info)
{
  const body = {
    intent: 'CAPTURE',
    purchase_units: [{
      amount:
      {
        value: info.usdAmount,
        currency_code: 'USD'
      },
      payee: {
        email_address: info.paypalEmail
      }
    }],
  }
  let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest()
  request.requestBody(body)
  return client.execute(request).then(res => {
        return {res: true, id: res.result.id}
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
        }
        return {res: false}
    })
}

function executePayment(info)
{
    console.log(info)
    const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(info.orderId)
    request.requestBody({})
    return client.execute(request).then((result) => {
      console.log("Payment suceed")
      return {res: true}
    }).catch(err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
        return {res: false}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly, you don't seem to be doing anything wrong. I tested the exact same thing except using a simple curl integration rather than node, and everything worked as expected.  Here are the curl requests so you can validate whether it works for you...

```sh
#!/bin/bash

access_token=$(curl -s https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "clientid:secret" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" | python3 -c "import sys, json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['access_token'])")

echo $access_token
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

access_token=$(./curl_rest_gettoken);

curl $@ -s https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
  -d '{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [
    {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "5"
            },
            "payee": {
                "email_address": "......@business.example.com"
            }
        }
  ],
    "application_context": {
            "return_url": "https://www.yahoo.com"
    }
}' | python -mjson.tool
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash

access_token=$(./curl_rest_gettoken);

curl -v -s -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/$1/capture   \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" | python -mjson.tool
```

Comment: Only part time on the project, so sorry for the delay of the answer and thank you for your help. 

It didn't worked and gave me the same result with your shell scripts. Meaning it is something from the paypal account I use, either my sandboxs (none of them work) either the app itself.

I will try to see with paypal where is the issue.

Comment: Have you created new sandbox business accounts in https://www.paypal.com/signin?returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F and a new REST app and tried with them instead? Try with US country ones if they are from another

Comment: Damn, that the REST app. I already recreated a REST app after your comment, but it didn't worked. Today, with despair I recreated a third one, and with no explanation, no code changed, it worked. It seems that Paypal really have issue with their REST API. Anyway, thanks a lot. You can change your answer so I flag your as the right solution.